# ASP.NET REPLACING Request.IsAuthenticated with a bool is generatig System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, replace, request, boolean

The errors:

[Breakpoints and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA6jP.jpg)

[Error from the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49NWE.jpg)

I want to replace the *Request.IsAuthenticated* because I have different register and login methods fro the standard template. I wanted to replace with a *bool*, I have also tried with an *int* as you will see in the code bellow.

This is my *AccountController.cs* login method where I'm using the bool *Authenticated* :

```
    //GET: Account/LoginTurist (new)
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult LoginTurist()
        {
            return View();
        }


        //POST: Account/LoginTurist (new)
         [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult LoginTurist(LoginVM obj)
        {
            bool userExists = db.Users.Any(u => u.Username == obj.Username && u.Password == obj.Password);

            var viewModel = new LoginVM { Authenticated = Request.IsAuthenticated };
            //var viewModel = new LoginVM { Authenticated = 0 };

            if (userExists)
            {
                Session["UseId"] = db.Users.Single(x => x.Username == obj.Username).Id;

                viewModel.Authenticated = true;
                //viewModel.Authenticated = 1;

                return RedirectToAction("Experiences", "Home");
            }
            // in case of incorect email or password
            ViewBag.LoginMessage = "Nume utilizator sau parola incorecte!";

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

This is the model LoginVM:

```
namespace TuristWithComments.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginVM
    {

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nume Utilizator")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required, DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Parola")]
        public string Password { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Recunoaste dispozitivul?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

        public bool Authenticated { get; set; }
        //public int Authenticated { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is the view, the *LoginPartial.cshtml*, where I a trying to replace the *Request.IsAuthenticated* like this:

```
@*@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity*@
@*@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)*@


@model TuristWithComments.ViewModels.LoginVM
@if (Model.Authenticated)


{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })*@
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
        </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("Inregistrare", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>*@
        @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("Autentificare", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>*@
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Inregistrare", "RegisterTurist", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Autentificare", "LoginTurist", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

I can understand that the *Model.Authenticated* is null (see the first picture) but where exactly can I fix this? *Request.IsAuthenticated* is from the beggining as *false* thats why the program runs at start.
How can I fix the Model to not be null?

Or is there maybe a better, different way of changing the Navbar, would you do it another way?

**Later edit:**
After searching for more answers online I see a lot of mentions about "Web.config", to witch I have not made any modifications and looks like this:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
```

Could here be the key? Maybe I need to modify something here?

**Later Edit 2**, after David's comment:
The LoginPartial view is part of the NavigationBar, witch is in the default Layout (or master Layout if you will) where all the pages render and theoretically is the first thing that opens when you run the project, no?!
Here is the Layout page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <!--Lightbox for popup images-->
    <link href="~/Content/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Acasa", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Recomandarile noastre", "Recommendations", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Experientele utilizatorilor", "Experiences", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Fii spontan!", "Spontaneous", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contacteaza-ne", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Despre noi", "About", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")      // <-- here it is
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="padding: 7px">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/_banner7.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-body">
        <div class="col-md-2"> 

            <!--Partial view for the sidemenu-->
            @Html.Partial("_SideMenu")

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-10">

            <div>
                @RenderBody()
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    @*<hr />*@
    <div class="container body-content">
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - TuristWithComments in Banat by Ionut Guruian</p>
        </footer>
    </div>



    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)

    <!--Lightbox for popup images-->
    <script src="~/Scripts/lightbox-2.6.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, the action does have a GET, I have added that aswell in the first code snippet.

And the LoginTurist.cshtml where the user puts his credentials to login is this one here:

```
@using TuristWithComments.Models

@model TuristWithComments.ViewModels.LoginVM
@*@model LoginViewModel*@


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Autentificare";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">

            @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginTurist", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Autentificare</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>


               @*<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>*@

                <h5 class="text-danger" style="padding-left:20%">@ViewBag.LoginMessage</h5>

                
             
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Autentificare" class="btn btn-success" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Inregistrare cont nou", "RegisterTurist")
                </p>
            }
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section id="socialLoginForm">
            @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to have anything to do with the `Authenticated` property.  `Model` is `null`.  Because you didn't provide the view with a model:

```
return View();
```

should be:

```
return View(viewModel);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the quick reply. I have made the necessary changes and placed the viewModel in the return of the AccountController, but the exact same problem persisted. the exact same error. Model is still null and it throws the exception like last time.

Comment: @IonutG17: I notice that the controller action shown is using `[HttpPost]`.  Is that the action that's showing this page, or is there a GET action being used?  How specifically is this page being loaded?  The view is also called `LoginPartial`, is this the entire view or is it being included within a parent view?  Any way you look at it, the error has the same root cause.  A model is not being supplied, so it's `null`.  Where are you loading this view and not passing it a model?

Comment: I have updated the question and added the GET action that exists in that controller (see the first code snippet). The LoginPartial si part of the NavigationBar witch is in the master layout, there is also the code for that.

Comment: @IonutG17: In the GET action you're not providing the view with a model.  So the same problem is happening for the same reason.  You also need to pass the model to the partial view: `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", Model)`  Anywhere that you want to use the model, you have to provide it with an instance of that model.